# Jquery accordion menu with image expander/collapser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I hacked some Jquery together to get my accordion menu more or less how I want it, except for this one issue.  I'm trying to add an image in the corner to act as the expander/collapser so that it can do its thing and the  tag before it can still do the navigation.

When I put it in using Jquery though, the  gets included in with the  tag.

```
$('#am_menu a').each(function() {
    if($(this).parent('li').children('ul').size() > 0) {
        $(this).append('<img src="http://goo.gl/S5j2J"/>');
    }
});
```

I know it has to be a fairly easy fix but I'm still pretty new to Jquery and am tired of looking at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/ezDWg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/9Hkxs/) and let me know if that helps any?

> BUMP

Updated fiddle to better fit what you where trying to do and to include support for even deep levels ( see Main 3 inside Main 2 )

Comment: Actually i just noticed a structual issue in comparison to yours, I will be updating it now, will put "bump" on answer when update complete